# MySQLi OOP Class Insert Function Not Working

Tags: php, class, oop, mysqli

I am currently practicing OOP, creating a MySQLi class that will have atleast the basic MySQLi functions (insert, select, update, etc). This is what I have got so far:

```
if(!class_exists('dbc')) {
class dbc {
    public function __construct($host = host, $username = username, $password = password, $database = database) {
        // Make the constants class variables
        $this->host = host;
        $this->username = username;
        $this->password = password;
        $this->database = database;

        $this->connection = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);

        if($this->connection->connect_errno) {
            die('Database connection error!');
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function __deconstruct() {
        if($this->connection) {
            $this->connection->close();
        }
    }

    public function insert($table, $variables = array()) {
        if(empty($table) || empty($variables)) {
            return false;
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ";

        $fields = array();
        $values = array();
        foreach($variables as $field => $value) {
            $fields[] = "'" . $field . "'";
            $values[] = "'" . $value . "'";
        }

        $fields = '(' . implode(', ', $fields) . ')';
        $values = '(' . implode(', ', $values) . ')';

        $sql .= $fields . ' VALUES ' . $values;

        $query = $this->connection->query($sql);

        if(!$query) {
            echo mysqli_error($this->connection);
        }

        echo $sql;
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, I create the connection via the details from the config file, I then send a query through the established connection. But for some reason when I attempt to create a MySQLi insert query, I just get the same error over, and over again:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''name', 'option') VALUES ('Sub Title', 'This is a test website')' at line 1

I even echoed out the sql query, which appeared to be the correct format:

> INSERT INTO options ('name', 'option') VALUES ('Sub Title', 'This is a test website')

I have spent hours of Googling, trial and error, etc, trying to fix this, and have had no luck, and as it's 12:30am, I'm tired and may be missing something critical, so if anyone knows what is causing this problem, it'll be greatly appreciated for a solution, etc.

Thanks,
Kieron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column names in the first set of parenthesis should not be quoted:

```
INSERT INTO options (name, option) VALUES ('Sub Title', 'This is a test website')
//                   ^^^^  ^^^^^^
```

Though you can use backticks `` ` `` around the column names e.g. `` `name`, `option` ``.

Comment: Just changed it, and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: If you changed it then the error would be different (it wouldn't say `...right syntax to use near ''name...` because that quote would have been removed). Can you post the exact error you're now getting?

Comment: Nevermind, I just realised I was using option as a column name, even though it's reserved via MySQLi... Bedtime me thinks. Thanks, I am trying to set your answer to green but there is a waiting period.

Answer (score 2):

Your connection is definitely not working as you are missing the `$` on these 4 lines infront of the parameter names

```
   $this->host = host;
   $this->username = username;
   $this->password = password;
   $this->database = database;
```

Should be

```
   $this->host     = $host;
   $this->username = $username;
   $this->password = $password;
   $this->database = $database;
```

Also the name you have used for your class deconstructor is incorrect it should be

```
public function __destruct() () {
```

yours will not cause an error but it will not run automatically on class destruction with your name.

@Marty is correct about the use of backticks and not single quotes around your query syntax, but I dont see how the connection gets made based on the first error I mentioned, and therefore how you get a sensible SQL error reported, however something may be going on that is not obvious from the code you showed us.

Comment: It looks like those may be constants somewhere (although it seems the `$` were still missed, but it would work either way if that's the case).

Comment: Odd that they should be passed as parameters in that case